# what is wrong in this two combobox code

Tags: c#-4.0

```
namespace Combobox
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conectionString"].ConnectionString);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [DISTRICT_NAME]FROM[JP_TP_MST] group by DISTRICT_NAME order by DISTRICT_NAME", con))
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {

                        comboBox1.Items.Add(reader[i].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [TALUKA_NAME]FROM[JP_TP_MST]where DISTRICT_NAME like N'" + comboBox1.Text + "%' group by  [TALUKA_NAME] order by TALUKA_NAME", con))
        {
            try
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {

                        comboBox1.Items.Add(reader[i].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }
        }
        con.Close();
```

Comment: What errors do you see?

Answer (score 0):

After the catch try to put the close method in finally function `catch(){ //your exception code} finally{ con.Close() ; }` 
 and con.Open() put it inside the try function because if the connection string is wrong or anything that is related to Opening the connection it will be handled in the catch exception